# How to pass a list in an array of pointers

Tags: c, list, struct

I have written a piece of code and I am trying to pass a list into an array of pointers but my pointers are nulls. I call the function from main as you can see at the bottom and I am trying to fill every pointer (`termatika[j]`) with a list but when I am going to print it I get null.

```
struct str {
    char mitermatika[61];  
    struct node *termatika[10];
} pinakas[100];

struct node {
    char terminalc[61];
    struct node *next;
};

void add( struct node *ptr,char buffer[] )  
{ 
    ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node ) );
    strcpy( ptr->terminalc, buffer );  
    ptr->next=root;   
    root=ptr;
}

void terminal(char buffer[],struct node *pointer) { 
    initnode();
    add( pointer,buffer);
}

void printnode( struct node *ptr )
{
    printf("Name ->%s\n", ptr->terminalc );
}
```

And this is in my main:

```
terminal(buffer,pinakas[i].termatika[j]);
printnode(pinakas[0].termatika[0]);
```

Comment: whats the problem with my code?

Comment: ahaaaa very nice soz again :)

Answer (score 0):

In C it's never really a good idea to try and pass an entire object (especially an array/list of objects) in a function call.  That uses a lot of stack space and causes the processor to copy a lot of memory from the heap to the stack eating up a lot of clock cycles.  Always pass objects by reference, or pointer.  That said, it looks like you are trying to write a linked-list algorithm (one of my favorite).  I suggest trying something like this:

```
typedef struct node_tag // <- Use typedef for easy reference in source
{
  char terminalc[61]; // <- This will allocate space for an array of 8-bit characters for each node
  node_tag *next; // <- Use struct tag to reference internally
} node_t; // <- This is the name of the node type to use in your source

node_t * nodeList = NULL; // <- Root pointer for your list.

void Add( node_t *ptr,char buffer[] ) // <- Remember char buffer[] is the same as char *buffer
{
  // ptr will already be pointing to allocated memory, so do not reassign.
  //ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node ) );

  strcpy( ptr->terminalc, buffer );

  // When adding to a link list ptr-next should always be NULL.
  ptr->next=NULL;

  root=ptr;
}

void main( void )
{
  ptr = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  Add( ptr, "Some character array" );
  ...
}
```

Or, if you *want* your memory allocation inside of `Add()`, you can do something like this:

```
void Add( char buffer[] )
{
  ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node ) );

  strcpy( ptr->terminalc, buffer );

  ptr->next=NULL;

  root=ptr;
}
```

Keep in mind that your `Add()` function should not always add to `root`, but it should look for the end of the list.  This can be done easily with a `while` loop, or your algorithm can maintain a separate `endOfList` pointer variable that always points to the last node in the list.